# Docker Volume without linking. What is the use case?

Tags: docker, volumes

So far, I really only understand VOLUME as a way to

- Specify a directory inside of a data container that will be persistent
- Specify a location that will link to your host container

What I am failing to understand is why I see so many Dockerfiles that use `VOLUME /path/to/app` or even worse `VOLUME /var/lib/mysql`. I understand that you might want to create a container that has this volume and then use `--volumes-from` to link to that container for persistence. But why would you make that specification inside the container that is actually using that data. How does it help? As far as I can see,  `VOLUME /var/data` is not any different than just saying `RUN mkdir /var/data`. How are volumes beneficial when they are not inside a data container, shared with the host, or being used by other containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker images and Docker containers have a layered file system which is slow. By defining directories as data volumes you instruct docker to [let those directories outside of the slow layered file system](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#data-volumes). This as multiple consequences among which:

- fast file system
- ability to share a volume between multiple containers
- persistence (as long as at least one container that use that volume exists)

This is why volumes are not only a commodity but a necessity for directories for which good I/O performances is expected.

---

> As far as I can see,  VOLUME /var/data is not any different than just saying RUN mkdir /var/data.

The difference is that with volumes the directory `/var/data` is a mount point on a different (and faster) file system. You can witness that `/var/data` is not just another directory by running the `mount` command in a container:

```
$ docker run --rm -v /var/data busybox mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
none on / type aufs (rw,relatime,si=6c354c296f850c3c)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=755)
shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=65536k)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=666)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/mapper/vg0-root on /etc/resolv.conf type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/vg0-root on /etc/hostname type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/vg0-root on /etc/hosts type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/vg0-root on /var/data type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
proc on /proc/sys type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc/sysrq-trigger type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc/irq type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc/bus type proc (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /proc/kcore type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=755)
```

`/` is on a **aufs** layered (and slow) file system

`/var/data` is on a **ext4** (and fast) file system

Comment: There is little or not speed impact when using the btrfs storage-driver, which is used by default if it's available.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I was unaware of this. Also note that btrfs comes with canveats as explained at [1](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#daemon-storage-driver-option) and [2](http://blog.docker.com/2013/05/btrfs-support-for-docker/)